# Adding a column to a table in sql java for android

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql, sqlite

I was trying to add column to a sql db that I created. this db is for learning purpes so ignore the names of the columns ..
I had many problems while trying to do so, but after a LOT of reading I saw few things :
1. I needed to change the DB version so it will start the onUpgrade method
2. I needed to add an "ALTER TABLE" command in my onUpgrade method.

after doing so, the app stopped throwing exceptions, and I thought everything is well.
the only thing is that if I try to update the table with the new column it doesn't update anything (even though for some reason it doesn't throw exception).

my main concern is if I should have added the new column commend to the onCreat or no
the onUpdate method I created was to add the KEY_KIDS column:

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
            int newVersion) throws SQLException{
        Log.w(DBHelper.class.getName(),
                "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE[0] +  " ADD COLUMN "
                +  KEY_KIDS + " text not null default kids; ");
        Log.w(DBHelper.class.getName(),
                "Columns added!");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE[0]);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE[1]);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE[2]);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE[3]);
        onCreate(db);
    }
```

this is the table that I whanted to add a columns to, the new column is KEY_KIDS:

```
 public static final String Table1= "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE[0] + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                KEY_AGE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_HOTNESS + " TEXT NOT NULL);" ; //
```

Should it be like this, or witho the KEY_KIDS declaration (KEY_KIDS + " TEXT NOT..)

pleas help. I have been trying to solve my problem for days and couldn't figure it out.
this is the whole code for the sql:

```
     package com.Dvir.newlearning1;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class HotOrNot {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "persons_name";
    public static final String KEY_AGE = "persons_age";
    public static final String KEY_HOTNESS = "persons_hotness";
    public static final String KEY_Hairy = "is_hairy";
    public static final String KEY_KIDS = "has_kids";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "NewDB2";
    private static final String[] DATABASE_TABLE = {"peopleTable", 
            "peopleTable2", "peopleTable3","peopleTable4" };
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    private DBHelper ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
        public static final String Table1= "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE[0] + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                KEY_AGE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_HOTNESS + " TEXT NOT NULL " + 
                KEY_KIDS + " TEXT NOT NULL);" ;
        public static final String Table2 = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE[1] + " (" +
                    KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                    KEY_AGE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_HOTNESS + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
        public static final String Table3= "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE[2] + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                KEY_AGE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_HOTNESS + " TEXT NOT NULL);" ;
        public static final String Table4= "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE[3] + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                KEY_AGE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_HOTNESS + " TEXT NOT NULL);" ;
        public DBHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) throws SQLException{
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL(Table1);
            db.execSQL(Table2);
            db.execSQL(Table3);
            db.execSQL(Table4);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
                int newVersion) throws SQLException{
            Log.w(DBHelper.class.getName(),
                    "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            /*db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE[0] +  " ADD COLUMN "
                    +  KEY_KIDS + " text not null default kids; ");*/
            Log.w(DBHelper.class.getName(),
                    "Columns added!");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE[0]);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE[1]);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE[2]);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE[3]);
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }

    public HotOrNot(Context c) throws SQLException{
        ourContext = c;
    }
    public HotOrNot open(){
        ourHelper = new DBHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
    public void close(){
        ourHelper.close();

    }
    public long creatEntry(String name, String age, String hotness, int table, String kids)
        throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_NAME,name);
        cv.put(KEY_AGE, age);
        cv.put(KEY_HOTNESS, hotness);
        cv.put(KEY_KIDS, kids);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE[table], null, cv);
    }
    public long creatEntry(String name, String age, String hotness,String hasKids, int table) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_NAME,name);
        cv.put(KEY_AGE, age);
        cv.put(KEY_HOTNESS, hotness);
        cv.put(KEY_KIDS, hotness);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE[table], null, cv);
    }
    public String getData(int table) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_HOTNESS, KEY_AGE};
        Cursor c;
        c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE[table], columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        String result = "";
        int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
        int iAge = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AGE);
        int iHotness = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_HOTNESS);

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iName) + " " +
                    c.getString(iAge) + " " + c.getString(iHotness) + "\n";
        }

        return result;
    }
    public String getName(long l) throws SQLException{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_HOTNESS, KEY_AGE};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE[0], columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + l, null, null,null, null);
        if (c !=null){
            c.moveToFirst();
            String name = c.getString(1);
            return name;
        }
        return null;
    }
    public String getHotness(long l) throws SQLException{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_HOTNESS, KEY_AGE};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE[0], columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + l, null, null,null, null);
        if (c !=null){
            c.moveToFirst();
            int iHot = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_HOTNESS);
            String name = c.getString(iHot);
            return name;
        }
        return null;
    }
    public String getAge(long l)throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_HOTNESS, KEY_AGE};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE[0], columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + l, null, null,null, null);
        if (c !=null){
            c.moveToFirst();
            int iAge = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AGE);
            String name = c.getString(iAge);
            return name;
        }
        return null;
    }
    public void updateEntry(int table, long lRow, String mHotness, String mAge,
            String mName) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();
        cvUpdate.put(KEY_NAME, mName);
        cvUpdate.put(KEY_AGE, mAge);
        cvUpdate.put(KEY_HOTNESS, mHotness);
        ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE[table], cvUpdate, KEY_ROWID + "=" + lRow, null);

    }
    public void deleteEntry(long lRow1) throws SQLException{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE[0], KEY_ROWID + "=" + lRow1, null);

    }
}
```

another thing - I have been trying to creat a multi table DB using a for loop. but, I don't know why, it doesn't let me do it. it tried doing something like:
    String[] table;
    for (int i = 0; i<26, i++) {
    table[i] = "CREATE TABLE " + "DATABASE_TABLE[i]" +...
    }
eclips keeps red flaggin the semicolon in te end of "table" with the error:
    Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token
does someone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this part :

```
public static final String Table1= "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE[0] + " (" +
            KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
            KEY_AGE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_HOTNESS + " TEXT NOT NULL " + 
            KEY_KIDS + " TEXT NOT NULL);" ;
```

You forgot the comma (`,`) just before the `KEY_KIDS` part.

Comment: For your second problem, you should write : `table[i] = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE[i] + " (..."`, but you'll get more replies in a different thread !

Answer (score 0):

This `onUpgrade` function does three things:

1. It adds the `kids` column;
2. it drops all tables from the database; and
3. it calls `onCreate`, which creates all-new tables.

The purpose of the `onUpgrade` function is to convert the database from some old version to the new version.
Just deleting the old database and then recreating it might be a valid way to do this (if you don't care about the data), but then you would not need to bother with ALTERing things.

Drop steps 2 and 3.

The `onCreate` function must create a database in the latest version, so it must include all columns of that version.

Answer (score 0):

edit the line

```
db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE[0] +  " ADD COLUMN "
+  KEY_KIDS + " text not null default kids; ");
```

to

```
db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE[0] +  " ADD COLUMN "
+  KEY_KIDS + " text not null default 'kids'; ");
```

notice the single quote 'kids'. if column is of type string (eg: text, varchar, char), put in quotes, unless the data type of type number
(eg: integer, decimal) no quotes needed.